# How to extract data from mysql for listview in tab?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I had created the activity class and the fragments for each of the listview. Each tab will display the list of items according category in the tab.

Activity class:

```
public class DisplayPostItem extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selected_navigation_item";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_post_item);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Books").setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Lab coat").setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tools").setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Others").setTabListener(this));
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)) {
        getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM, getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_post_item, menu);
    return true;
}



@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    /**
     * On first tab we will show our list
     */
    if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
        BooksFragment booklist = new BooksFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, booklist).commit();
    } 
    else if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
        CoatFragment coatlist = new CoatFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, coatlist).commit();
    }
    else if (tab.getPosition() == 2) {
        ToolFragment toollist = new ToolFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, toollist).commit();
    }

    else {

        OtherFragment otherlist = new OtherFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, otherlist).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return textView;
    }
}
}
```

--EDIT--

Is this the right way to get the information from mysql? The code below has several errors.

Fragment class:

```
public class BooksFragment extends ListFragment {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json;

ArrayList<Products> productsList = new ArrayList<Products>();

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/project/display_items.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "product";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_BUDGET = "price";
private static final String TAG_DES = "description";
private static final String TAG_DATE_POSTED = "created_at";
private static final String TAG_CATEGORY = "category";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String TAG_CONTACT = "contact";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, books);
    setListAdapter(listAdapter);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<Products>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.des))
                    .getText().toString();
            String price = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.budget))
                    .getText().toString();
            String date = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date_posted))
                    .getText().toString();
            String category = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category))
                    .getText().toString();
            String email = ((TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.email_request)).getText().toString();
            String contact = ((TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.contact_request)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    DisplayItemInfo.class);
            // sending information to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);
            in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_DES, description);
            in.putExtra(TAG_BUDGET, price);
            in.putExtra(TAG_DATE_POSTED, date);
            in.putExtra(TAG_CATEGORY, category);
            in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, email);
            in.putExtra(TAG_CONTACT, contact);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
}

class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(BooksFragment.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        // getting attached intent data
        String jsonS = intent.getStringExtra("JSon");

        if (jsonS == null) {
            // getting JSON string from URL
            json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);
        } else {
            try {
                JSONObject Jsonobj = new JSONObject(jsonS);
                json = Jsonobj;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String budget = c.getString(TAG_BUDGET);
                    String description = c.getString(TAG_DES);
                    String category = c.getString(TAG_CATEGORY);
                    String contact = c.getString(TAG_CONTACT);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE_POSTED);

                    if (category == "Books") {

                    // Create a new Product Obect, set its Values
                    Products mProduct = new Products();
                    mProduct.pid = id;
                    mProduct.name = name;
                    mProduct.price = budget;
                    mProduct.description = description;
                    mProduct.date = date;
                    mProduct.category = category;
                    mProduct.email = email;
                    mProduct.contact = contact;

                    // adding Product to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(mProduct);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainMenu.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();

        if (productsList.size() > 0) {
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getBaseContext(),
                    productsList);// ,

            if (getListView() != null) {

                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                Log.d("ListView-Reference", "ListView is null");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("Product List", "Products list is empty");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you select any tab then related of that fragment class is called then you have to place your populate listview code on onCreateView method because onCreate is calling when your fragment class is set but not called again and again but onCreate view to setup own fragment view so you called your code in onCreateView Method.

Comment: i have edited the fragment class. is that way correct?

Comment: You have to set adapter after getting resource id of listview else listview returning null every time.

Answer (score 0):

The common practice is to do all the data fetching tasks n the onCreateView() on the fragment you have just selected but keep one thing in mind if you try to put your tabs in ViewPager in future, then make sure you write the code in onResume since onCreateview would be called even before you select it as Its the property of ViewPager to also load the very adjacent tab of the tab you just clicked.